# Installed debian packaage

Tags: dpkg

I have a debian package(.deb) and i installed it using `sudo dpkg -i /path/to/deb/file` and `sudo apt-get install -f`. when i use try to list it works fine,but when i try to know the installed files and its location, it tells me that the package is not installed.(check the terminal output below). I do not understand how it is installed and it can not find it. i do not understand how. am i missing something. i checked the location where it is installed, by checking the contents of the .deb using dpkg -c and the installed files exist

```
(base) hisham@hisham-XPS-L421X:/etc$ dpkg -l | grep libprecice
ii  libprecice2                                2.0.2                                            amd64        Precise Code Interaction Coupling Environment
(base) hisham@hisham-XPS-L421X:/etc$ dpkg -L libprecice
dpkg-query: package 'libprecice' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
(base) hisham@hisham-XPS-L421X:/etc$
```

Comment: The *package name* is often different from the name of the .deb file. Specifically, your `dpkg -l` output is telling you that the package is called `libprecice2` not `libprecice`. Try `dpkg -L libprecice2`

Comment: i tried it you are correct, the package name is libprecice2, and it lists the file location when i run the command with -L flag